# Add form fields to a rotated page in pdfBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a requirement to add adobe form fields to an existing pdf.

The problem I encounter is when adding fields to a rotated page, the resulting form field text orientation is incorrect.

e.g. A page that is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, results in form field where the text is "vertical". 
[image: page rotated 90 degrees results in text having 90 orientation]

Is there a workaround to get form fields created with the correct orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance characteristics dictionary (/MK entry) of the widget has an /R entry where the rotation can be set. See e.g. [this file](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12770263/mypdf.pdf).

```
PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance
        = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
fieldAppearance.setRotation(90);
widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);
```

You may have to adjust your coordinates. To find the best coordinates, use PDFDebugger and hover at the place you want your field to be.

Update:
For checkmarks (and radio buttons) where the appearance stream is created by the user and not by PDFBox (as seen [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CreateCheckBox.java) or in the PDFBox [example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java?view=markup)) you need to set the matrix yourself like this (for 90°):

```
yesAP.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1, rect.getWidth(), 0));
```

The "1" here is for 90°. The translation needs to be adjusted for the other rotations.

Comment: Thanks. The only part I'm missing now is when clicking on a checkbox (i'm using code from https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CreateCheckBox.java) while clicking the box the check is incorrectly orientated but shows correctly when no longer focussed on checkbox.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't think on that one. The solution will likely be adding a rotation matrix + translation to the appearance stream (pdAppearanceStream). In the file I mentioned, it is 0 1 -1 0 NUM 0. NUM is the x width of the field rectangle.

Comment: OK, here's what worked on my own checkbox example: `yesAP.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1, rect.getWidth(), 0));`
 Please tell whether that worked for you (this is for 90° only, 1 = 90°), if yes, then I'll include it in the answer.